# Just use mixins from bootstrap, without having the entire bootstrap code in my css(after saving the less file)

Tags: css, less, web-essentials

after I save my changes in the less file, my original css file will also be updated.
The problem here: I use @import "bootstrap" in my less file for some mixins and the entire external bootstrap lines will be copied in my normal css.

How can I just use the mixins without that  "Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2" copies the entire source code to my css file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can import only the parts of Bootstrap that you need. This is a really good practice to get into, since as you have seen Bootstrap will include a lot of CSS that you probably don't need. For example, depending on your project's directory structure:

```
@import "bootstrap/mixins.less";
```